# iPhone integration with Amplify

Tags: swift, aws-amplify

I am trying to integrate iPhone with Amplify using this tutorial

https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/ios#add-amplify-to-your-application

but I am getting this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNEkw.png)

I am using xcode 11.7.

Comment: Are you unable to upgrade Xcode? It sounds like you need to use a lower version of amplify, try to specify that after entering in the url into SPM. Also, I can't tell, but are you attempting to install an 'unstable' version of amplify?

Sometimes to determine older versions I will go to the release timelines of the products(amplify) and attempt to match it up with the current version at that time for the other product(xcode and its build tools)